# How to detect when (forward) slash key is pressed in OEM keys C#

Tags: c#, wpf, key, slash

I'm working on wpf c# application and I need to detect when user press "**/**" but I'm having trouble with finding " **/** " e.Key, I saw there is `Key.OemBackslash` and stuffs like that, but I can't find right event for " / " (forward slash) ...

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: how about `e.KeyChar` ?

Comment: @SelmanGenç there is no e.KeyChar in wpf, I should include windows form library than it will mess up with my MessageBoxes which exist in win form also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Key.OemQuestion` on a US keyboard. But on a Swedish keyboard it is `D7` so it depends. The keys on the keyboard doesn't always produce the same character.

Depending on what you are trying to do you may be better off handling the `PreviewTextInput` event:

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    if (e.Text == "/")
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: @I'm working with WPF and I'm using this event Window_PreviewKeyDown and looks like there is no propery Text for e..

Comment: No there isn't. That's why you could handle the PreviewTextInput of the WPF window instead of the PreviewKeyDown event...Otherwise Key.OemQuestion is the closest you get to a "/" key.

Comment: by the way mate, then is there way to detect when enter is pressed? for example first check for a e.Text and after that check if enter is pressed, how could I do it if my sender is not KeyEventArgs, instead of that it is TextCompositionEventArgs .. and TextCompositionEventArgs  does not contain e.Key== Key.Return..

Comment: Handle the PreviewKeyDown event to detect ENTER key presses and the PreviewTextInput event to detect "/"? ENTER is not a character and "/" is not a key.

Answer (score 1):

You can the following methods ([see this site](http://huddledmasses.org)) to get the character from the key.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
        bool toUnicodeIsTrue=false;
        char t = GetCharFromKey(e.Key, ref toUnicodeIsTrue);
        if ( t == '/')
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);  
}


    public static char GetCharFromKey(System.Windows.Input.Key key, ref bool toUnicodeIsTrue)
    {
        toUnicodeIsTrue = true;
        char ch = ' ';

        // First, you need to get the VirtualKey code. Thankfully, there’s a simple class 
        // called KeyInterop, which exposes a static method VirtualKeyFromKey 
        // that gets us this information
        int virtualKey = System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);
        //Then, we need to get the character. This is much trickier. 
        //First we have to get the keyboard state and then we have to map that VirtualKey 
        //we got in the first step to a ScanCode, and finally, convert all of that to Unicode, 
        //because .Net doesn’t really speak ASCII
        byte[] keyboardState = new byte[256];
        GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

        uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey((uint)virtualKey, MapType.MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(2);

        int result = ToUnicode((uint)virtualKey, scanCode, keyboardState, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity, 0);
        switch (result)
        {
            case -1:
                toUnicodeIsTrue = false;
                break;
            case 0:
                toUnicodeIsTrue = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                {
                    ch = stringBuilder[0];
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    ch = stringBuilder[0];
                    break;
                }
        }
        return ch;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, MapType uMapType);
    public enum MapType : uint
    {
        MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0x0,
        MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK = 0x1,
        MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x2,
        MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX = 0x3,
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ToUnicode(
        uint wVirtKey,
        uint wScanCode,
        byte[] lpKeyState,
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out, System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 4)]
        StringBuilder pwszBuff,
        int cchBuff,
        uint wFlags);
}
```

**My old Answer:**

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{ //***
    if (e.Key == Key.Oem2)
    {  
        // do stuff
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

Note that the name starts with "oem" (Original Equipment Manufacturer), which means the keyboard manufacturer is responsible for its functionality and it varies in local keyboards. So, you can set a break point in

```
{//***
```

line of my code and check e.Key property.

Comment: unforunately Key.Oem2 is not being triggered when I hit forward slash :(