# How do I create a XAML KeyBinding for CTRL+'

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings, apostrophe

In a WPF MVVM application I need to trigger a command when CTRL+' (control and apostrophe) is pressed. None of the following will compile...

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="CTRL" Key="'" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
<KeyBinding Modifiers="CTRL" Key="\'" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
<KeyBinding Modifiers="CTRL" Key="&apos;" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+'" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+&apos;" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+\'" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

So how can this key combination be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An apostrophe is not a key. It's a character that is eventually mapped to a key depending on the input device. `OemQuestion` works on my keyboard:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="CTRL" Key="OemQuestion"  Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

...but you may be better off handling the `PreviewTextInput` event if you really want to detect when an apostrophe is typed in:

[How to detect when (forward) slash key is pressed in OEM keys C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058394/how-to-detect-when-forward-slash-key-is-pressed-in-oem-keys-c-sharp/42066151#42066151)

Comment: OemQuestion doesn't work on my keyboard but, as you say, it needs handling via a keystroke event of some kind. I've added a handler to the PreviewTextInput event on the datagrid where the keystroke needs handling but it's not firing for some reason. Nomatter, I get the principle and I'll work it out. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The key code for apostrophe is OemQuotes. This syntax should do the trick

```
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Command}"
          Modifiers="CTRL" Key="OemQuotes" />
```

Comment: That compiles but the command doesn't fire. The Oem part makes me think it may relate to a niche keyboard of some kind.

Comment: I noticed that in the Key type converter, (System.Windows.Input.KeyConverter), they are using the "QUOTES" key token. I replaced "OemQuotes" with "QUOTES" and it seems to be working.

Comment: QUOTES isn't an option for the Key parameter. VS gives you a dropdown of all the available values and that's not one of them. I also tried using Gesture="CTRL+QUOTES" and "CTRL+QUOTE" but no joy.

Comment: Have you checked what key code is received, when ' key is pressed, in the callback of KeyDown event on your keyboard? Both Gesture="CTRL+QUOTES" and Gesture="CTRL" Key="Quotes" are working fine on my side.